# Composition Over Inheritance - Avoiding Abstract Classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, composition

I was reading this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) about composition over inheritance and in the example they used an abstract class. Let's say you wanted to avoid they use of abstract classes completely and only use concrete classes. I want to know, is my example a proper use of composition. Let's say I have the following IGameobject interface.

```
    public interface IGameObject
    {
        string Name {get;}
    }
```

and the follwing weapon interface:

```
    //Note the IGameObject getter
    public interface IWeapon
    {
        int Damage {get; }
        IGameObject gameObject {get;}
    }
```

Normally, in my game, a weapon **is-a** IGameObject. However, considering that we're using composition, according to the wiki article it's a **has-a** relationship.

Now, I could do this when creating a Sword object:

```
public class Sword : IWeapon
{
        private IWeapon weaponObject;

        public Sword(IWeapon weapon)
        {
            this.weaponObject = weapon;
        }

        public int Damage
        {
            get
            {
                return this.weaponObject.Damage;
            }
        }

        public IGameObject gameObject
        {
            get
            {
                return this.weaponObject.gameObject;
            }
     }
```

}

I can now store my sword in a collection, for example, a List:

```
List<IWeapon> weapons = new List<IWeapon>();
weapons.add(swordObj)
```

and still have access to my IGameObject.

Now, I have a 3 questions:

1. Have I implemented composition correctly?
2. Should my Sword class also implement `IGameObject` interface?
3. Is it okay that my IWeapon contains a `IGameObject getter`? (The reason is, if I store it as an IWeapon, with no IGameObject getter, how then would I get the details of the `IGameObject`?)

Comment: This looks very odd - your `Sword` class is just a wrapper around `IWeapon`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're avoiding behavior-adding methods in your interfaces and sticking to properties instead?

Comment: This is not has-a. It's is-a because the same object has multiple aspects. This is not amenable to composition. Composition is not better than inheritance. It's for different things.

Comment: @DavidL - It's not actually game code or production code, I found the artcle on wiki, and decided to try it for myself

Comment: @Lee - How then would you implement composition given the above interfaces and classes?

Comment: The composition here is between `IWeapon` and `IGameObject` not `Sword` and `IWeapon`. I would expect `Sword` to implement `IWeapon` and contain an `IGameObject` under that scheme, and have `Sword.Damage` return some constant value. Whether composition between `IWeapon` and `IGameObject` is a good idea is hard to say. I would probably expect `IWeapon` to be a subinterface of `IGameObject` and not use composition at all.

Comment: Leaving aside the problem of composition vs inheritance, there are many other problems here. Why is "damage" a property of the weapon? Surely damage will be computed by taking into account the weapon, the wielder, and the resistances of the target; why should any one of these things have responsibility for the computation?  There are a lot of pitfalls in this domain; if this subject interests you, check out my series of articles on it: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Composition vs. Inheritence is a very important principle to grasp, however, like any principle, it has a positive effect only if properly applied.
In order to properly apply it, you must understand how it came to light.

C vs I was thought of because developers 'went to town' on OOP, especially in languages like C++ where multiple inheritance is allowed. Everything went downhill pretty quickly, design-wise, as you can imagine.

It is easy to think of this principle in the following manner:
We as OOD system designers wish to model domain object relationships in a manner which most resembles the domain we would like to mimic- therefore we need to look at these relationships closely and carefully.

Whenever you are about to inherit, do consider whether or not inheritance closely describes the real world relationship between the entities in question.

In your case, a weapon is infact a game object, so inheriting is actually a good idea and will promote polymorphism along the way.

Here is an example of how C vs I may apply in your domain:

```
interface IGameCharacter
{
  ICollection<IWeapon> Weapons {get;}
  ICollection<IGameCharacter> Party {get;}
}
```

Comment: +1 for "C vs I was thought of because developers 'went to town' on OOP". I see a historic parallel between back in the day when OOP spread and today where functional programming becomes more mainstream. The old day OOP gurus made promises and clouded the rather simple mechanics of OOP into a scientific myth. After a while, people figured out ways to produce working OOP systems and developed best practices. Yet, what worked back then still works today: Start with your use cases and the surface area of your sub-system, then implement as you see fit. Well defined subsystems keep your system sane.

Comment: @BitTickler. Spot on.

Comment: @EyalPerry - Just one question, is it okay if my IWeapon has a IGameObject getter? So When I implement my IWeapon, I also have to return an IGameObject?

Comment: That depends on the relationships of this IGameObject with the IWeapon.. Do you have any specific relationship in mind? btw, feel free to ask as many questions- it is refreshing to answer principle related issues and not silly lmgtfy type questions.
@S.R

Comment: Well, I thinking of is-a relationship in that case IWeapon would implement IGameObject directly.

Comment: If IWeapon is a IGameObject, there is no need for a getter property of that type, just have IWeapon extend IGameObject.. this is a healthy practice in this case. @S.R

Comment: @S.R Also, please accept the answer (click on the V) if it answered your question.

Comment: @S.R It all comes down what you want to do (use cases): Can you drop a weapon from the character? Can others pick it up - jump on it - destroy it or does it vanish from the scene when dropped? Do you have "attach/detach" operations to combine game objects at run time? Your intended functionality drives your design.

Comment: @S.R sidenote: you should check out the "SOLID" set of principles, while you are at it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: @EyalPerry - I have looked into SOLID principles and understand it somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

What you used here is called the decorator design pattern. You create a new class that extends some superclass (IWeapon). This class is called the decorator (Sword). The class contains an object of the same type as the superclass - this object is called the decoratee (weaponObject). Some of the decorator's responsibility is transferred to the decoratee. In practice this means that the decorator calls at least one of the decoratee's methods in one of its algorithms (in your case the decoratee is used for both Damage and gameObject).

The point of this is to avoid re-implementing some behaviour in the decorator that is already present in the decoratee. If the decoratee already has the required behaviour and you want this behaviour in your decorator, then the decorator pattern is a good choice.

The other option would be subclassing the decoratee and inheriting the wanted behaviour but that introduces other problems related to subclassing (tight coupling, inheriting some unwanted behaviour in addition to the wanted behaviour, exposing things from the decoratee that should not be exposed to the decorator, etc.). If you want the benefits of composition, you must implement the decorator pattern (or a similar pattern) instead of subclassing. Bear in mind though, that the concrete type of the decoratee can change at runtime and it is this type that determines what behaviour you will get in your decorator class. This can be very useful to support changing behaviour at runtime but it is also something you must be aware of when implementing the pattern.

Now, as for whether the decorator pattern is the right choice in this situation, I propose to you the following question: Do you want your Sword class (your decorator) to take advantage of some behavior from another subclass of IWeapon (your decoratee) and do you want to be able to change this behavior at runtime? If you can answer yes to that question the decorator pattern is a good fit.